# What is the \begin{LaTeX} environment for?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm very sorry if this is something obvious, but I haven't been able to find anything on this. 
I'm generating LaTeX files using Org-mode in Emacs. The generated source file has

```
\begin{LaTeX}
...
\end{LaTeX}
```

sections. When I use latexmk to make a pdf, these sections show up with LaTeX written above whatever is enclosed in this environment (in the kind of font you get from the \latex command). I'm wondering what this environment is and where it might be used.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Any command `\foo` can be written `\begin{foo}...\end{foo}`, then `\begin{foo}` will do `\foo` (and some housekeeping) and `\end{foo}` will do (basically) nothing.

In your case, it's just writing `\LaTeX` at `\begin{LaTeX}`.  Even though it works, it's probably syntax you shouldn't use :-)

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks. I'll have to look at a way to prevent emacs from generating this in the first place.